# A proof involving matrices (checking working)

Tags: matrices

> Matrices $A,B$ and $C$ are all $2 \times 2$ matrices and $C=A-CB$. Assuming that $(I+B)^{-1}$ exists, prove that $C=A(I+B)^{-1}$, where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

I was wondering if someone could check my work:
\begin{align}
C=A-CB  
&\iff C+CB=A  \\
&\iff C(I+B)=A  \\
&\iff C=A(I+B)^{-1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, looks fine. Assuming that $(I + B)^{-1}$ is invertible almost finished the question. A good question to ask is : When do you think it is not invertible?